# between extends Activity and extends AndroidApplication

Tags: android, libgdx

I want to call

```
public class main3D extends  AndroidApplication  {
        public void onCreate (android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                initialize(new genarate3D(), false);
        }

}
```

by this class

```
public class mainPage extends Activity
{
    private ImageView mHome;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);

        mHome = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgVtownHome);
        mHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(mainPage.this, main3D.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
```

but there is error

```
09-28 08:38:56.886: E/AndroidRuntime(24439): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

09-28 08:38:56.886: E/AndroidRuntime(24439): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets.main3D

09-28 08:38:56.886: E/AndroidRuntime(24439): at com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets.mainPage$1.onClick(mainPage.java:24)
```

how could I fix this?
thank you.

Comment: You can't start an application as activity. Why do you not create another activity or a service?

Comment: I'm sorry because I use "class main3D extends  AndroidApplication " to render 3D object

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What error are you getting? AndroidApplication extends Activity, so there should be no problem launching it via Intent. Perhaps you didn't declare main3D as an Activity in the manifest?

Comment: Hi nEx.Software thank you for your replay. I've edited the question and I already declared main3D in the manifest.

Comment: That exception indicates you are not exporting your core project and/or the libgdx jars. Check the Order and Export tab of the Java Build Path to make sure you are exporting everything.

Comment: Now I solved the problem thank you for helping nEx.Software and all of you guys

Comment: @nEx.Software Could you add that as an answer, please?